# What is the most efficient way of inserting 199 millon rows of data?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a 2.2 GB text file in the format of:

```
1234567890
1234567890
etc.......
```

I need to insert each line into a table (field 1) such as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [field1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [field2] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
```

What is the most efficient way of inserting this data?
Is there a premade program that can be used? (i.e can it be done from the command line externally)

I've created a script and I select 1,000 records create a sql query around them and then insert. This takes a while, is there a better way? (Better as in easier, faster, less overhead)

Note: I've tried 1M, 100,000, 10,000 batch sizes, but the query is long at those sizes, so am stuck with 1k for now.

(query used)

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2)
SELECT '1234567890','123'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234567890','123'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234567890','123'
// etc....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) is likely to be the best tool for the task. SQLFool has a good [BCP basics article](http://sqlfool.com/2008/12/bcp-basics/) on its usage.

@Marian posted a comprehensive list of [BCP optimisation references](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5025/optimising-bcp-performance-for-blob-data) in response to a question I asked, which you may find useful.

Answer (score 5):

Use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) and remove constraints from the destination table.

Comment: Thanks this is good for other situations, but for this task bcp is how I'll go.