# Exporting tables from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, export

I have to export some data from SQL Server 2012. I'm interested in flat file export (i.e.: `.csv`) but my database has about 500 tables.

Here is an example for you to better understand the situation:

- Database: ETTEDB_list
- Table1: list_20140101
- Table2: list_20140102
- .
- ..
- ...
- TableN: list_20151706

All these tables have the same structure (number of columns, column names, data types).

Is there any way to automatically export all these tables into `.csv` files for later joining into one ore more BIG `.csv` files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to export a table to a text file](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-export-a-table-to-a-text-file)

Comment: INSERT INTO My_Big_Table SELECT * FROM Tables1...N? Then export My_Big_Table as .csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

1. Use the gui of SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Use BCP to export your data in a loop ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms162802.aspx))
3. Use Powershell and script your export in a loop for example.

Here an example in PowerShell:

```
 $Tables = invoke-sqlcmd -query "SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'list[_]%'" -database "ETTEDB_list" -serverinstance "YOURSERVER"
 foreach ($Table in $Tables)
 {
     $TableName = $Table["name"]
     write-host -ForegroundColor White "Creating File $TableName.csv"
     invoke-sqlcmd -query "SELECT * FROM $TableName" -database "ETTEDB_list" -serverinstance "YOURSERVER" |export-csv -path c:\scripts\$TableName.csv
 }
```

You'll need to adjust "YOURSERVER" to the right value and maybe change the path property to the correct folder. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Would you please consider me a newbie in Powershell/MS SQL Server and point me straight to an already written script or command to do what am i supposed to?

Comment: I've added a PowerShell example.

Comment: Also if you want to put it all in a single CSV in the end anyway you could use dynamic SQL to create a UNION ALL view and just use any of the above tools to export the contents of the view.